# Why this string is not valid JSON

Tags: json, validation, delphi

```json
[{"OperId":1,"OperEmri":XXXX,"OperPass":YYYY,"OperShifra":222222222,"OperNrFisk":111111111,"OperKompania":ZZZZ,"OperVendi":ZZZZ}]
```

Delphi's REST Debugger returns "CONTENT IS NOT JSON".

Can anyone tell me why?

---

This string is generated automatically, this is the code:

```
JsonArray := TJSONArray.Create;
if QryUser.RecordCount > 0 then begin
  try
    QryUser.First;
    while not QryUser.Eof do begin
      JsonObject := TJSONObject.Create;
      with JsonObject do begin
        AddPair('OperId', TJSONNumber.Create(QryUser.FieldByName('OperId').AsString));
        AddPair('OperEmri', TJSONNumber.Create(QryUser.FieldByName('OperEmri').AsString));
        AddPair('OperPass', TJSONNumber.Create(QryUser.FieldByName('OperPass').AsString));
        AddPair('OperShifra', TJSONNumber.Create(QryUser.FieldByName('OperShifra').AsString));
        AddPair('OperNrFisk', TJSONNumber.Create(QryUser.FieldByName('OperNrFisk').AsString));
        AddPair('OperKompania', TJSONNumber.Create(QryUser.FieldByName('OperKompania').AsString));
        AddPair('OperVendi', TJSONNumber.Create(QryUser.FieldByName('OperVendi').AsString));
      end;
      //AddFieldsToJSON(JsonObject, QryUser);
      JsonArray.AddElement(JsonObject);
      QryUser.Next;
    end;
  finally
    Response.ContentType := 'application/json';
    Response.Content := JsonArray.ToJSON();
    JsonArray.DisposeOf;
    QryUser.Close;
  end;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need `""` around the string values, like this:

```json
"OperEmri":"Njazi"
```

Numbers should be without the `""`.

In answer to your second post:

Use `TJSONNumber` for numbers only, you should use `TJSONString` for strings.

Comment: You can't use the answer space to bypass not yet having the comment privilege. If you have a comment and don't have that privilege, you simply cannot comment.